# Why is ngModelController.$validators undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

This doesn't make much sense since the directive with the error in question is working just fine on another page I'm running.

#### The error

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'qtMatch' of undefined`

#### The directive where the error occurs

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.directive('qtMatch', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                otherModelValue: '=qtMatch'
            },
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                // errors happens here 
                ngModelCtrl.$validators.qtMatch = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                    return (scope.otherModelValue == modelValue);
                };

                scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$validate();
                });

            }
        };
    });
})();
```

What this is telling me is that `ngModelCtrl` is undefined. But why? I have a similar form using this directive just fine.

#### The form in question

```
<form name="resetPasswordForm" action="/Account/ResetPassword" method="post" ng-controller="resetPasswordController" ng-strict-di novalidate>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Code)

    <h2>Reset your password</h2>

    <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="Email" ng-model="Email" placeholder="Email" required />

    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="Password" ng-model="Password" ng-class="{ 'validationError' : resetPasswordForm.Password.$invalid && resetPasswordForm.Password.$touched }" required minlength="8" ng-pattern="/\d/" />

    <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" 
           ng-model="ConfirmPassword" ng-class="{ 'validationError' : resetPasswordForm.ConfirmPassword.$error.qtMatch && resetPasswordForm.ConfirmPassword.$touched }" required minlength="8" ng-pattern="/\d/" 
           qt-match="Password" />

    <input type="submit" class="LoginSubmit" value="Reset Password" ng-disabled="resetPasswordForm.$invalid" />
</form>
```

#### The controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('resetPasswordController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        }]);
    })();
</script>
```

Any ideas what is going on? I have tried evaluating the value of `ngModelCtrl` immediately before the call to validate and it looks like this:

```
$dirty: false
$error: Object
$formatters: Array[1]
$invalid: false
$isEmpty: (value)
$modelValue: NaN
$name: "Password"
$parsers: Array[1]
$pristine: true
$render: noop()
$setPristine: ()
$setValidity: (validationErrorKey, isValid)
$setViewValue: (value)
$valid: true
$viewChangeListeners: Array[0]
$viewValue: NaN
```

I'm using Angular 1.4.x.

Comment: You have duplicate `name="Password"` elements

Comment: Off-topic but confirmation fields (password, email, etc) are definitely out of fashion these days.

Comment: @Phil, fixed, but did not solve the issue. Also, I know re: confirmation fields, but I'm just the guy trying to build it here...

Comment: Do you have an "ng-model" in the input you're trying to put the directive?

Comment: @EchoLogic could you try putting a breakpoint (or type `debugger;`) at the top of your directive's `link` function, inspect `ngModelCtrl` and put the contents into your question

Comment: Seems to me works well. I've tried [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/0cLwcwyx/32/) with version of angular 1.4.6